# Use CMake to generate Visual Studio Python projects

Tags: python, cmake, visual-studio-2017

Can CMake generate Python projects for Visual Studio 2017?
I can generate them manually but prefer to automate it using CMake.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

CMake currently doesn't have support for such a generator (available generators are documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html))

Would you like to eventually share and discuss the idea with the CMake team and potentially help integrate such a feature into CMake ? If yes, I could help you and guide you through the process.

I also wonder if creating a [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) template for a python project allowing to build compiled extension by leveraging CMake (thanks to [scikit-build](https://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) wouldn't be a viable solution too ?

Comment: given generator list says it supports `Visual Studio 2017` but does not mention which languages are supported that supported by `Visual Studio 2017`. Is there any documentation regarding that?

Comment: Good point, here is a merge request trying to clarify the type of project supported by the generator. Let us know what you think. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2262

Comment: Also here is the CMake issue where the support for Visual Studio Python Project  is being discussed. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17956